# Why css position relative with all properties auto?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I happen to see some responsive [sites's](http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Baked-Onion-Dip-TasteOfHome) list happen to have css position relative like below:

```
position: relative;
top: auto;
right: auto;
bottom: auto;
left: auto;
```

Care to know why is it being coded like this? Any preferences or tips about this ?

Comment: For what element(s)? // Might be to overwrite values set earlier, or “just to be sure” … you’d probably have to ask the site’s author for a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto` is the default value of the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties.. It's essentially the same as saying "none" or "no value" (The reason it isn't actually written as `none` is because technically every element always has a value for each of those properties, but by default it is just calculated by the browser, and not explicitly listed in the CSS anywhere.. hence the term `auto`). In most (all?) cases, setting the value to `auto` would be done to override a previously set value, and return it to it's default behaviour, or done pre-emptively to prevent those values by being set (perhaps a plugin is being used that automatically adds those properties, but the developer decides they do not want that behaviour to ever occur).

In terms of "tips" about this, if you do not expect to need to reset that value, you probably don't need to include these rules.. In my experience, I only ever set these properties to `auto` if I discover that I have already set the value to something else and need to reset it.. never pre-emptively.